# Python scrapy error "Callback is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running this very basic code

```
import scrapy
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']
```

Running the code using

```
scrapy runspider scraper.py
```

And I get an error as follows:

```
2020-07-21 08:54:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://brickset.com/sets/year-2016> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\navne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\navne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in parse     
    raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: BrickSetSpider.parse callback is not defined
2020-07-21 08:54:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Please help. Sorry for such a trivial doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `parse` method to collect the required information

```py
import scrapy


class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

    def parse(self, response):
      #search what you need
      # yield your result
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the parse method, which by default gets called, containing the response of start URL. This will work for you.

```
import scrapy
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']


    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text) # this will show response (source code)
```